# Specifying Glue::Crawler with JdbcTargets on CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I'm trying to set up AWS Glue to read from a RDS Postgres using CloudFormation. In order to do that I need to create a crawler using the JdbcTarget option. (Or do I not?)

```
  Records:
    Type: 'AWS::Glue::Crawler'
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: transact
      Targets:
        JdbcTargets:
          - Path: "jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/database"
      Role: !Ref ETLAgent
```

But creating the stack on CloudFormation wil fail with:

`CREATE_FAILED   |   AWS::Glue::Crawler  |   Records |   Connection name cannot be equal to null or empty. (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException;`

Even though [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-crawler-jdbctarget.html#cfn-glue-crawler-jdbctarget-connectionname) say:

> *ConnectionName*
>
> The name of the connection to use for the JDBC target.
>
> Required: No

What is the correct AWS Glue setup using CloudFormation that will allow me to read from RDS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're really missing the `ConnectionName` property, which should carry the name of connection resource which you're missing. The `Path` property you're setting is used to select the schemas/tables to crawl (`dbname/%/%` to include all). Consult [CloudFormation docs on Crawler JDBCTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-crawler-jdbctarget.html) for details.

Your template should look something like

```
  MyDbConnection:
    Type: "AWS::Glue::Connection"
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      ConnectionInput:
        Description: "JDBC Connection to my RDS DB"
        PhysicalConnectionRequirements:
          AvailabilityZone: "eu-central-1a"
          SecurityGroupIdList:
           - my-sec-group-id
          SubnetId: my-subnet-id
        ConnectionType: "JDBC"
        ConnectionProperties:
          "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/database"
          "USERNAME": "my-db-username"
          "PASSWORD": "my-password"
  Records:
    Type: 'AWS::Glue::Crawler'
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: transact
      Targets:
        JdbcTargets:
          - ConnectionName: !Ref MyDbConnection
            Path: "database/%/%"
      Role: !Ref ETLAgent
```